# android setVisibility does not display if initially set to invisble

Tags: android, layout, visibility

I have a glsurface occupying the full screen. At the click of a button I want another layout to appear (settings type of thing). If I start with the overlay being visible, I can make it invisible and then visible again with no problem. But if I start with it invisible, I cannot make it ever visible again. Code follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/glPlaySurface"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</android.opengl.GLSurfaceView>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btnRotate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="R"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btnPan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="P"
        android:textColor="#000" />
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLights"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:text="Lights" />

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutLights"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:visibility="visible" <--- Does not work if set to invisible
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

    android:background="#fff" >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLightsOK"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:text="OK" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLights"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:text="OK" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


private OnClickListener mOnLightsClick = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(mLayoutLights.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            mLayoutLights.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            mLayoutLights.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: the problem is related to the glsurface. If i replace the glsurface with an ordinary surfaceview it works fine.

Comment: more info: if I set the glsurface to GONE, the set the layout to VISIBLE, then set the glsurface back to VISIBLE - it works. But... if I set the glsurface to INVISIBLE instead of GONE - it does not work.

Comment: ok - the surface_view_overlay in the api demos does exactly what i'm looking for - i'm gonna see where i went wrong and then post.

Comment: run set visibility on UI Thread :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Got it. You have to set the visibility of all the items in the layout, not just the layout. So this code worked:

```
if (mLayoutLights.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLightsOK)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLightsCnc)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
mLayoutLights.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    mLayoutLights.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLightsOK)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLightsCnc)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 34):

Had similar error but it was due to my silly mistake of not using the UiThread.

```
Activity act = (Activity)context;
act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run() {
    mLayoutLights.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
} });
```

Comment: Thank you man, it solved my problem ! I was setting the visibility in a callback, and had no idea why the view wasn't updated immediately, but now it works. It seems that I need to work on UI threads..

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 11):

In my case, with a plain SurfaceView, I just set the View to GONE in xml, not INVISIBLE. Then I can set VISIBILITY correctly after that.

Comment: This is really a very nice answer

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same problem and debug log was clearly showing that the visibility is correctly set.

I was using databinding. For me the solution below worked.

```
activity.runOnUiThread(() -> binding.getRoot().post(() -> {
    binding.additionalDataHolderOne.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    binding.firstStreamHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}));
```

Actually, `binding.getRoot().post(() -> {});` did the job.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest trying three independent things.

1. Changing layout width and height to wrap content as it could be an issue with matching the parent.
2. Calling bringToFront on the view
3. Wrapping the surfaceView in a FrameLayout (this is related to #2, but it still might help)

Comment: Thanks - but none of those made a difference.

Comment: Do you know if the render thread is running or even starting on the  surface?

Comment: yes - the 3d responds to touch and renders properly (I've tried both render continuously and render when dirty - no difference)

Comment: I mean specifically in the case when it starts invisible.  It would seem like the renderer isn't running when you start it invisible.  Is it still running?

Comment: yes it is - the 3d responds and renders correctly when the other layout is visible or invisible.

Comment: after two god damn days your second suggestion (bringToFront) saved me. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you set the CalendarView to visibility "VISIBLE" and in the inflateView/OnCreateView after you find it with "findById" just set to "GONE" and you can do what ever you want with it.

> calendarView = (CalendarView)
>         view.findViewById(R.id.all_scores_calendar_view);
>               calendarView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>
> calendarView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Answer (score 0):

I don't why is not working (for me also) but as a workaround you can do:

```
 val params = mLayoutLights.layoutParams
    if (shoouldShow()) {
        params.height = WRAP_CONTENT
    } else {
        params.height = 0
    }
    mLayoutLights.layoutParams = params
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a problem like this before I was put 2 views in a LinearLayout.
one of the 2 views is gone and the other one is visible.

and when I try to make the gone one visible and the visible one gone,
it was not working.

I solved this issue by using RelativeLayout as a container layout instead of the LinearLayout, It's working fine then.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have called **.setVisiblity(View.GONE)** in an element where visibility is **GONE**

```
 if (temp.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            temp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

doing something like that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just changed layout id and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **ViewBinding** and you have a nested View via **Include** with a View whose Id is the same as in the main View, there may be a situation that the Visiblity property is not applied to one of these Views

Answer (score 0):

i don't know whats reas of not working but i put my layout into cardview and set cardview visiblity gone and it's work for me

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/rec"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardTxtResult"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardTxtResult"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/main_rec"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:stackFromBottom="false"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

and java code connected to checkbox

```
 CHK.setOnCheckedChangeListener((compoundButton, b) -> {
        if (b) {
            rec.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            rec.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -3):

```
case R.id.title_call_button:
if(llButtonCallNow.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE){
llButtonCallNow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
    else{
    llButtonCallNow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ("Im here baby :)"),
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
break;
```