# Setvisibility doesn't work on Buttons

Tags: android, view, visibility

I have a bunch of buttons aligned in a `TableLayout` in different rows. So when I go through them in a loop and call `btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` some of them get hidden, but others don't. And it works randomly. Sometimes they all hide, other time it works partially. What is the problem?
I tried to write `setVisibility` method call in the post method of the root view. It doesn't help either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android setVisibility does not display if initially set to invisble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556730/android-setvisibility-does-not-display-if-initially-set-to-invisble)

Answer (score 0):

Try the "alpha" option instead.

```
btn.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(0);
```

You can set the duration in miliseconds in order to get an animated type of look. This should help.Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it gives the same result.

Answer (score -1):

Try `btn.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Comment: very clever! :) First of all, I tried if of course. And second, I don't actually need behavior like GONE. I need to make a button invisible.